# Reshaping dataset to correct size

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I'm trying to learn tensorflow and I'm trying to import the handwritten dataset from sklearn but I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 1797, 64]
```

My code:

```
X,y = load_digits(return_X_y=True)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape=X.shape))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
```

What is the correct shape?

Answer (score 0):

A `Conv2D` layer expects input of the following shape: `(num_examples, height, width, channels)`. You are looking for a `Conv1D` layer, because your input shape (according to the error) is of shape: `(num_examples, height, width)`.

Answer (score 0):

`load_digits` returns a flattened array, so you need to reshape to 8x8 and unsqueeze.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import datasets
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

X,y = datasets.load_digits(return_X_y=True)

X = X/255.0

X = X.reshape(-1, 8, 8, 1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.build(input_shape=(8, 8, 1))

model(X)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1797, 3, 3, 64), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.79972278e-03, ...,
          3.92661383e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 2.93043372e-03],
         [3.34757613e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
          4.03874973e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
         [5.52046159e-03, 1.12290974e-04, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]]]]
```